# Does Mac OS X have the /dev/ptmx file?

Tags: c, linux, macos

I want to port my Linux application that uses pseudo-terminals to OS X, but I can't seem to find the `/dev/ptmx` file on my OS X Tiger.

Is it because OS X Tiger is so old, and newer versions have this file?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and I see there are `/dev/ttyXX` and `/dev/ptyXX`.  I think that's one way of doing it (maybe the older, more manual way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Tiger is a bit too old, OS X 10.5 Leopard added the `/dev/ptmx` interface. If you want to run on Tiger you'll need to manually iterate through the `/dev/ptyXX` devices until you find one that opens successfully (see section 3.1.2 of http://chschroeder.gamiro.de/rg/or1ksim_macOS10.4.pdf)